# How to define array of objects in Sequelize.js?

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

How can I define an array of objects field in Sequelize.js model? 
I need something like this

```
{
    "profiles" : [
        {
            "profile_id": 10,
            "profile_pictures" : ["pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg","pic3.jpg"],
            "profile_used_id" : 12
        },
        ... // more profiles
    ]
}
```

I checked the [docs](http://sequelizejs.com/docs/1.7.8/models#data-types), but couldn't find a relevant data type, am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

I have successfully been mimicking arrays by defining my model like:

```
var MyModel = sequelize.define('MyModel', {
    myArrayField: { 
        type: DataTypes.STRING, 
        get: function() {
            return JSON.parse(this.getDataValue('myArrayField'));
        }, 
        set: function(val) {
            return this.setDataValue('myArrayField', JSON.stringify(val));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: with defaultValue: '[]'

Comment: with type: DataTypes.STRING

Answer (score 13):

I can think currently of 2 solutions (and a 3rd one if you are using PostgreSQL).

1. We have a relational database working behind, so do its principles apply also for Sequelize which is a ORM for relational databases. The easiest would be to create another table or entity and associate them as a 1:n relationship.
   For that matter add a new model in Sequelize and define its associations like described here: http://sequelizejs.com/articles/getting-started#associations
   You might have then 2 tables. One profile table having N pictures.
2. If its just a filename or url you could serialise a Javascript array to a JSON string like:

   // before save

   var mypics = ["pic1.jpg","pic2.jpg"];
   profile.pictures = JSON.stringify( mypics );
   profile.save()

   // after load before use

   var profile = Profile.get(1)
   pictures = JSON.parse(profile.pictures);
3. If you use PostgreSQL you could use the Array Datatype for this field, see:
   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.4/static/arrays.html

   or the JSON Datatype:

   http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/datatype-json.html

Go for 1 if your Picture object is or will be more complex in the feature. Or if you want to query by filename.
Go for 2 if you dont do any data filtering or complex data in the future.

Go for 3? I think its best to stick to Sequelize abstraction and not use custom data types even its possible in that case. Maybe you better stick to 1 or 2.

Comment: So Let's say I use Postgres, I would define the array of Objects like Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSON) right?

Comment: Sequelize.ARRAY(Sequelize.JSON) does not work